# Why would content served by Traefik be truncated?

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have a Traefik reverse proxy in front of several docker containers in my dev environment.

I noticed recently that large files are being cut off when served over port 80 (Traefik). However, if I download the file using the local HTTP port on the Docker container, the file is fine.

This seems to only affect files that exceed a certain size.

I generated a large file on one of my Docker containers like so.

```
for ((i=1;i<=200000;i++)); do echo "$i some new line that has a reasonably long length and content" >> public/large-file.txt; done
```

If I `curl` the file and bypass Traefik (port 4200 on this container), the file is intact and the same exact size every time. If I `curl` the file over port 80 via Traefik, the file is cut off at a seemingly random point.

```
$ curl -O http://localhost/large-file.txt; cat large-file.txt
...
114633 some new line that has a reasonably long length and content
114634 some new line that has a reasonably long length and content
114635 some new line that has a rea

$ curl -O http://localhost/large-file.txt; cat large-file.txt
...
199732 some new line that has a reasonably long length and content
199733 some new line that has a reasonably long length and content
199734 some new line that has a re
```

Based on this behavior, it seems to me that this is not a Docker issue, and not an issue with my web-server. Rather, it seems like Traefik is at fault.

Is this a bug in Traefik, or a potential misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official image is https://hub.docker.com/r/_/traefik
The  https://hub.docker.com/r/containous/traefik is made by the traefik team but contains experimental tags etc...

About your problem, it may be linked to an issue in 1.5.0-rc as you can see on this issue (https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2637), but this will be fixed in the next 1.5 release